# Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial 3 - Ch. 2 Ex 2.2 - cannot get Rails Generate Scaffold User... to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Trying to learn the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial book, hung up right now: Section 2.2

example says:

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

I get:

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\demo_app>rails generate scaffold User name:string email:
string
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
34:in `require': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/demo_app/Gemfile:4:in `evaluate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21
/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:57:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:57:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/rails_projects/demo_app/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (require
d)>'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please set me on the right track?  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a space between `email:` and `string`

Comment: no, sorry, that's just from pasting it here.  there was no space when the error occurred.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the rails generate command. Can you share your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you are a new comer to rails 3 but if not and also if you are, i think **DEVISE** is a good gem to use .i have finished the book and i used devise for my authentication system. all you need do is install it manually from github so as to read its documentation and also more tutorials on ASCiiCast and railscast for videos  (engaging with devise). it as a lot of methods that is used in the book e.g if signed_in, current_user, logged_in e.t.c and also destroy the user model before using **DEVISE**.

Answer (score 0):

I would review your Gemfile to see that you have everything entered correctly.

HTH